# Compare two shapes and identify different points

Tags: javascript, geometry, shapes

I want to add the extra 2 points in the middle from first shape (point 4&6) to the 2nd shape, before and after point 4 of the 2nd shape.
Each shape is an array of [x,y] points following the given order.

How should I start this?
[image: two shapes with different points]

Comment: Do you need to identify what points are different, or only if there are more points? 

If both shapes are an array of points and you only need to find if 1 has more points than the other, you can use array.length for that

Comment: What is a "*shape*" from data structure perspective?

Comment: Since this question is likely to evolve into "what library to use?" consider moving it to another "Stack" site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Each shape is an array of [x,y] points. Their order defines the shape. The two shapes have the same starting points (let's say lower-left extreme corner)

Comment: I would need to identify that point 5 and 7 in shapeA are the same as point 4 and 5 in shape B. And points 4 and 6 in shapeA are before and after point 4 in shapeB.

Comment: Is it always the left shape that has additional points, or it may also happen to the right shape? Does the provided example cover all your needs? I mean things can be way more difficult if it was "S" character from different fonts. For example, the "lower-left extreme corner" can be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

An intermediate point along a line segment PQ is obtained vectorially by a linear combination (1-t) P + t Q. Find the t for the points 4 and 6 on the left and insert the similar points on the right.